# Plotting eigenfunctions for various values of a parameter

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, graphics

Mathematica beginner here. I've been playing around with it a bit and reading various bits of documentation, but getting nowhere fast. I thought I'd describe what I want to do, and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction please.

I have a linear ODE operator that depends on a parameter "l", on a domain $r \geq 0$. I want to consider a finite domain cutoff "RAD" and particular value of "l", and solve for the first several eigenfunctions and eigenvalues. I seem to have done this, and plotted the graphs of these functions together on the same plot, using Plot and NDEigensystem

Now I'd like to do this for various values of "l", and increasingly large values of RAD. But somehow gather these nicely and display them nicely.

I think what I'd like is the plot I have with several eigenfunctions plotted together, but somehow make a button/slider appear to be able to click through various values of l and RAD, and cause the plot of the eigenfunctions to change appropriately.

Any help appreciated. Is there a nice function(s) that would help me do that? Is there any better idea on how to present the information nicely?

Comment: It will be significantly easier to provide a solution if you include the code you are using in your question :)